# How to replace a column data in linux output - may be using awk sed etc

Tags: linux, scripting, sed, awk

Basically I'm trying to compare the output of two files(one from PC which converts .cpio file to the layout format using standard tools, and another from embedded device using busybox tools), both of them produces the file system file/directory layout in 'ls -l' format. But the problem i got now is the output from embedded device prints the directory with some size info, which is not present .cpio.

Hence i have decided to replace directory content lines with 0 bytes size for the size column.

output from device :-

```
drwxrwxr-x    2 root     root          5512 Aug 22  2013 bin
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Aug 22  2013 bin/addgroup -> busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Aug 22  2013 bin/adduser -> busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Aug 22  2013 bin/ash -> busybox
```

output from PC :-

```
drwxrwxr-x   2 root     root            0 Aug 22 09:32 bin
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root            7 Aug 22 09:24 bin/addgroup -> busybox
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root            7 Aug 22 09:24 bin/adduser -> busybox
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root            7 Aug 22 09:24 bin/ash -> busybox
```

By comparing the output i have two issues to fix.

1) directory size is not shown correctly, i want to use awk/sed to replace this with '0' on device side.

2) similarly '09:32' time needs to be replaced with '2013', if i know how to do the first i will do the second by myself.

Please share you ideas to fix this.

Comment: `Please share you ideas to fix this.` -- Very nice way of saying `please do this for me`.

Comment: If you normalize the output and ignore the middle columns then both snippets are identical.

Comment: @devnull, i actually want to solve this myself but im not an awk / sed expert. I'm working on these tools on demand basis, i have tried couple pages in stackoverflow still i dont understand how to resolve this, hence i requested users to help me. You flagging this question as useless does not really solve my problem, or anybody who will come across the same. Even though i have asked this question here, im still working on it parallel to fix this. If you cant help me on this, stop hurting me. Someone with good heart might come forward to help me here.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth unfortunately i cant ignore the size column for all fields. I can ignore this for directory but not for files, since the purpose of comparison to detect the change in file size.

Comment: @rk.infotek.ltd I'm sure `someone with good heart` will come forward and do it for you.  They probably forget: `Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.`

Comment: @devnull - im not asking people to give me direct answers here, im asking suggestion to solve my problem. So please stop being unhelpful, do u have any thing to say about the problem to solve this issue ? if not please leave this page and let me get some help.

Comment: @devnull can u revert your minux mark on this question, since it is a genuine and proper question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat foo.input
drwxrwxr-x    2 root     root          5512 Aug 22  2013 bin
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Aug 22  2013 bin/addgroup -> busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Aug 22  2013 bin/adduser -> busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Aug 22  2013 bin/ash -> busybox

$ cat foo2.input
drwxrwxr-x   2 root     root            0 Aug 22 09:32 bin
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root            7 Aug 22 09:24 bin/addgroup -> busybox
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root            7 Aug 22 09:24 bin/adduser -> busybox
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root        12345 Aug 22 09:24 bin/ash -> busybox

$ diff <(awk '/^d/{$5=0}{$6=$7=$8=""}1' foo.input) <(awk '/^d/{$5=0}{$6=$7=$8=""}1' foo2.input)
4c4
< lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7    bin/ash -> busybox
---
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12345    bin/ash -> busybox
```

- `/^d/{$5=0}` sets field (column) 5 to `0` if the line matches `^d` (= starts with `d` = directory)
- `{$6=$7=$8=""}` deletes fields 6, 7, 8 for all lines since you want to ignore the date in your output
- print results and `diff` their output

Comment: sorry i need that column to compare my vital information to check.

Comment: @rk.infotek.ltd Updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Preserving spacing:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN{ preRE="^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){4}" }
    /^d/{
        match($0,preRE)
        preLgth=RLENGTH

        match($0,preRE "[^[:space:]]+")
        strLgth=RLENGTH-preLgth

        $0 = substr($0,1,preLgth) sprintf("%*s",strLgth,0) substr($0,preLgth+strLgth+1)
    }
    1
' file
drwxrwxr-x    2 root     root             0 Aug 22  2013 bin
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Aug 22  2013 bin/addgroup -> busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Aug 22  2013 bin/adduser -> busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Aug 22  2013 bin/ash -> busybox
```